# ARKit : Setting custom origin for ARWorldTracking Session

Tags: camera, augmented-reality, vuforia, arkit, compass

Whenever I start my Camera with ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and run the session, the initial origin would be exactly at the point where the camera is located with respect to the world.

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
        self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

However, I need origin to be at the custom location to start the AR experience. Would it be possible to modify the origin after starting the session?

Let's say I want origin to be at the place where the marker is located. Can I shift the origin to the center of the marker?

Comment: possible duplicate [update-only-the-world-coordinates-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270579/arkit-update-only-the-world-coordinates-origin)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the world origin to a specific place. You can only reset the whole tracking

```
session.run(configuration, options: .resetTracking)
```

It'll reinitialize all of the tracking that's going on and your camera position will start out again at 0, 0, 0.

Comment: ...any help...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296294/how-to-convert-a-position-into-starting-point-for-app-using-unity-and-arkit?noredirect=1#comment93496457_53296294