# How to convert a position into starting point for app using unity and ARKit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

Trying to develop an AR app.When the app is opened,at that point the device location is (0,0,0) that is if I print or display my coordinates it will be (0,0,0).I want to create a starting point like at the entrance of a door.When other users using my app can open the app anywhere.

What I am trying to do is I already kept an AR at the entrance of the door.Users open app at random position which become their starting point, all AR objects will appear.When they  pass through the AR object ,I want the coordinates of their device be(0,0,0).But if I run the below code in unity editor it **takes the camera** to the position where app has started.I am looking to convert the entrance position into App starting point.

```
            Camera.main.transform.position=new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

From what I understand if we change the position of camera in app it can show glitches

Comment: Need better undersanding on this.
You need something like a save checkpoint?
You play, you reach position B, you save and when you reopen the game, you want to start from position B?

Comment: No,for AR app it is required.When I reach a point I want to set that point as starting point,so that from that point I can calulate distance and do other calculations.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly you want the opposide of what you provided: Move the entire Scene so that the camera is at `(0,0,0)` related to the moved Scene?

Comment: @derHugo I want to add a Gameobject when I pass through it.It is triggered and the camera position/the user position must be at (0,0,0).Similar to app starting at that point.I dont want to restart but Camera position should reset.

Comment: so what is the problem with your current code / hwat does not work? Sorry I'm still not understanding completely ... **do** you want to set it to (0,0,0) or are you looking for another position?

Comment: **> so that from that point I can calulate distance**.   You can always calculate distance from a point by doing `Vector3.Distance(fromPoint,toPoint)`. You don't need to do any repositioning to do that.  It seems like instead of trying to move everything relative to the camera, you would be better off remembering a single changing reference point location, and doing your calculations relative to that.

Comment: I want plot in a 2d space for that I have to make door entrance as (0,0)=(x,z) values.With respect to that point I am plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear -.-

but **IF what you try doing is reset the camera to (0,0,0) while keeping all game objects at the same relative position to it** you could try:

```
    var localToCamera = Camera.main.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
    var obj = GameObject.FindSceneObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject));
    foreach (var o in obj)
    {
        var go = (o as GameObject);
        go.transform.FromMatrix(localToCamera * go.transform.localToWorldMatrix);
    }
```

_

**EDIT:**

what the **UGLY** code above is supposed to do:
it's going to crawl through all GameObjects and reposition them in such a way that if you set the camera to position (0,0,0) and facing (0,0,1), they will remain at the same position and orientation relatively to the camera.

notice that the camera itself WILL get repositioned to (0,0,0) and facing (0,0,1) after this code is executed because

Camera.main.transform.worldToLocalMatrix * localToWorldMatrix == identity

**EDIT**:

I can't put this code in the comments because it's too long.

try

```
// code from the top of my head here, syntax or function names might not be exact
var forward = arcamera.transform.forward;
forward.y = 0;
arcamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookDirection(forward);
// now the camera forward should be in the (x,z) plane
UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().SetWorldOrigin(arcamera.transform);
// since you did not tilt the horizontal plane, hopefully the plane detection still detected vertical and horizontal planes
```

Comment: To be fair the question is not really clear .. but so is your answer. Could you add some more information and explain what exactly this does and how it is supposed to solve the issue?

Comment: @Daveloper Yes, much better. No idea if that's what OP wants/needs but this seems like a good answer if that is the case.

Comment: So I guess he does want to do pretty much what I tried to do, except that I ONLY took care of virtual objects, he actually needs the ENTIRE tracking system to perform a coordinate system change. The question should specify whether you are using  ARKit or ARCore or anything else, and those frameworks surely have the infrastructure to perform such a coordinate change

Comment: hey I think i came up with this article..I think this is what I want.Please check setWorldOrgin..https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/02/16/developing-for-arkit-1-5-update-using-unity-arkit-plugin/ .

Comment: @Daveloper Any idea how to subtract from the position and make that point origin.

Comment: are you using ARkit? are you using ARcore? Are you using Holo toolkit, are you using... what are you using for your AR? You're not making it easy to answer your question ;)

Comment: @Daveloper...I SAID ARKIT IN MY QUESTION...:) I am using ARKit testing in Ipad...When I set the world to Origin by calling  this code.....UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().SetWorldOrigin(arcamera.transform);          ...the plane tracking acts weird.....The app doesnt work that smooth.

Comment: you need to make sure you preserve the x,y,z directions or at least the (x,z) plane should be horizontal, otherwise your plane detection system will start trying to detect tilted planes (horizontal and vertical in your new coordinate system).